# Limit rows in child documents with C# MongoDB driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a list of parent documents and each has a collection of child documents. I want to filter on a set of parent document ids, but also limit the types of child documents that come back.

In other words, I don't want to filter the parents *based* on the child documents, but rather filter the parents, *then* filter the children in those parent documents. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear such a thing is possible. To get the behavior I wanted, instead of having child documents, I created a new collection for the child documents to exist in and added a foreign key back to the parent document.